# no json output given from the server

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have simple table with two columns and 1406 rows. I want to get a json output from it to my android application. But the problem is no output is generated if i use **des** value with the query.  I can take an output from material value, but if I use **des** no output is given, even i use only **des,** no output is generated. If I use **limit** around 400, then there is a output with **des**. I tried both XAMPP and WAMP. Same result.

My php file.

```
<?php

 require_once 'include/Config.php';
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("connection failed");
    //mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE,$con) or die("db selection failed");


        $r=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT des from tbl_test_mas_material");

        $result = array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
                array_push($result, array('des' => $row[0]));
        }

                $json['feed']= $result;
                echo json_encode($json); 

    mysqli_close($con); 

?>
```

If I changed the query to **"SELECT des from tbl_test_mas_material limit 400"**, then there is an output.

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_test_mas_material` (
  `material` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `des` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`material`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**I can provide the CSV file also.**

Comment: Did you look at your `php error log` for any useful error messages like `memory limit exceeded`

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: What are you using now WAMPServer or XAMPP

Comment: i am using XAMPP server

Comment: Its here `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Comment: What do you mean by this: "But the problem is no output is generated if i use des value with the query" ?

Comment: that mean 'des' column. 
this will not give an output  - **"SELECT des from tbl_test_mas_material"** , 
but this will give the output - **"SELECT material from tbl_test_mas_material"**

Comment: @RiggsFolly no error showing. no error message also not showing in the browser. only blank page. mouse pointer animate "working in background" for couple of second and then nothing happen

Comment: In that case does the **des** column actually exist in that table

Comment: yes. if i use **limit** key word for example limit 400 , then there is an output

Comment: there are 1406 rows .

Comment: Try adding backticks around **des** like this `SELECT \`des\` from tbl_test_mas_material`

Comment: then this error come - 

<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\ceat_sap\available_products_test.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
{"feed":[{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null},{"des":null}.....

Comment: Which is line **15**

Comment: array_push($result, array('des' => $row[1]));

Comment: Your original code was `array_push($result, array('des' => $row[0]));` which was right `[1]` does not exist

Comment: Any luck using `[0]`?

Comment: still the same sir, no output. If you can check i can give you the CSV file of my table

Comment: how can i give it?

Comment: Do an export as SQL and paste that into a patebin or something

Comment: here is the file   http://pastebin.com/jaUSyWix

Comment: That is not a database backup that I can easily restore into my database. Please use something like `phpMyAdmin` EXPORT to export just that one table

Comment: I have the CSV file. but there is no upload section in pastebin

Comment: I dont have time to fanny about with CSV's lookup some sort of database backup for that one table so I can import it easily to my database

Comment: @RiggsFolly try this  http://pastebin.com/pubMcXs0

Answer (score 0):

> $sql = 'select `des` from `tbl_test_mas_material`';
>
> $res = $con->query($sql);
>
> while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($res))$arr[]=$row[0];
>
> $arrJS = json_encode($arr);
>
> echo $arrJS;

Comment: This is really not moving things forward and you have used OOP syntax for the query but the OP used a procedural connection, and you lost his assoc array creation

Comment: xampp i think has phpmyadmin. run the same sql there, do you get output?

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes to your script and then run it from your browser, you should then see any error message it may produce.

I have added some error checking for the MYSQLI calls and also set error reporting on with display errors set in case you are running this on a live server where these useful debugging aids are normally turned off.

I also simplified the array creation you were using

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once 'include/Config.php';
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$r=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `des` from tbl_test_mas_material");
if ( $r === false ) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    exit;
}

$result = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( array('feed' => $result) ); 
?>
```

The JSON String should be shown on the browser, or any error message you may have been suppressing.

Comment: this error coming - - **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ceat_sap\available_products_test.php on line 9**

Comment: Opps: TYPO Alert. I forgot the `;` on the `mysqli_connect()` line. Fix it and try again

Comment: TYPO Alert is gone. But still no output. I tried again with limit key, then there is the output.. Still the problem remaining and no error in the log also

Comment: Have you looked in the `mysql error log` I think its in `\xampp\mysql\data\something.err`

Comment: if i limit to 1239 output is given, that is the last number i can get the output. So i export my db and open with notepad++ . So i check line no 1239, In line no 1240 there is again a  **INSERT INTO `tbl_test_mas_material` (`material`, `des`) VALUES** query .

Answer (score 0):

**.........Solution..........**

Finally I figure it out. The problem was with the **json encode** as i figure it out. So i went with an alternative way. This is the final code.

```
<?php
require_once 'include/Configg_t.php';
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$result = $conn->query("SELECT tbl_inventory.qty, tbl_mas_material.des, tbl_inventory.plant, tbl_mas_material.matgrp, tbl_inventory.material from tbl_inventory inner join tbl_mas_material 
                    on tbl_mas_material.material = tbl_inventory.material where tbl_inventory.qty > 0 and tbl_inventory.type = 'D' order by material");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"qty":"'  . $rs["qty"].'",';
    $outp .= '"des":"'   . $rs["des"].'",';
    $outp .= '"plant":"'  . $rs["plant"].'",';
    $outp .= '"matgrp":"'   . $rs["matgrp"].'",';
    $outp .= '"material":"'. $rs["material"].'"}'; 
}
$outp .="]}";

$conn->close();

echo ( '{"feed" : ' . $outp);
```